# Replaceing Backbone sync on an Application level -- not via Model or Xollection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, amd

How does one replace Backbone.sync using backbone.basicauth library found here.

Can that be done on an Application level -- on App.init in main.js for example -- and avoid overriding the "synch" on every Model or Collection

[project](https://github.com/fiznool/backbone.basicauth)

[source](https://github.com/fiznool/backbone.basicauth/blob/master/backbone.basicauth.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can override Backbone.sync function and it will override the function used by all models and collections

```
Backbone.sync = function(){
    //Your code
}
```

More info

http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-134

Comment: Ah. right. Somewhat obvious now. Thanks. And that code generally would go right below the App.initialize in main.js in an AMD app. Or even before it i suppose.

Comment: You should put it before executing any ajax request. Usually this happens before calling `Backbone.history.start()` if you're using Backbone Routers of course. This is because the ajax requests are usually called when a view is rendered and this view calls its related collection or model and so on. This is my pattern

Comment: fair enuff. so one further question. given that the backbone.basicauth.js seems to not only override the sync function but the class object too. (its called Backbone.sync for example)  im guessing you only needs to 'include' that file and it does its work of function substitution. or do i need to do something like Backbone.sync = function( ) { return BasicAuth.sync() }